# BigCommerce Stencil - Retrieve Product Custom Fields in Product Card

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to retrieve each product's `custom_fields` data on the category list pages in BigCommerce Stencil. This documentation [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/product-resources), and the JSON product representation below, would suggest this is not possible.

It is hard for me to believe this functionality would be left out of Stencil, considering it was available in Blueprint.

```
{
    "id": 691,
    "name": "Archipelago Botanicals - Pomegranate Lip Gloss",
    "url": "http://******.mybigcommerce.com/archipelago-botanicals-pomegranate-lip-gloss/",
    "brand": {
      "name": "Archipelago Botanicals"
    },
    "rating": 0,
    "availability": "",
    "summary": "Pomegranate lip gloss leaves lips hydrated, shiny and smooth. Apply liberally.Net Weight: 0.42 oz. / 12 g Mineral Oil, Polybutene, Octyidodecanol, Butylene, Ethylene, Styrene Copolymer, Ethylene, Propylene, Styrene Copolymer, C18-36 Acid Triglycerides, Fr",
    "image": {
      "data": "https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/*****/images/stencil/{:size}/products/691/41439/arbopolipgl__77026.1464267682.jpg?c=2",
      "alt": "Archipelago Botanicals - Pomegranate Lip Gloss"
    },
    "date_added": "Apr 7th 2016",
    "qty_in_cart": 0,
    "pre_order": false,
    "has_options": false,
    "show_cart_action": false,
    "price": {
      "without_tax": {
        "formatted": "$5.00",
        "value": 5
      },
      "rrp_without_tax": {
        "formatted": "$12.50",
        "value": 12.5
      },
      "saved": {
        "formatted": "$7.50",
        "value": 7.5
      },
      "tax_label": "Tax"
    }
  },
```

Am I missing something, or is this functionality not available on Stencil at this time?

Has anyone come up with a creative solution to retrieve this data inside each product card?

Thanks

Comment: That's correct, the custom field isn't exposed to the category page. We have a feature request open to reintroduce this.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks

Comment: @Alyss has this been added yet?

Comment: Yes, it has. @DevinLuby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `product card` now allows this to be exposed. It provides an array of all custom fields associated with a product. Information on the product card object is [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/common-product-card-model).

It was a change that had to be made in the BC core app and the fix was released on Sept 20th