# Access Product Variant Price with Stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

With the legacy API, I can obtain product variant prices for productId 100 with the following:
`https://something.com/api/v2/products/100/skus.json`

But in the Stencil documentation for [Product](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/product-resources#Product), there is no price property for a product attribute SKU, and the available properties that are available are limited vs the legacy API.

With `product`:

`"values": [
          {
            "label": "Hardcover",
            "id": 98,
            "data": "Hardcover",
            "selected": false
          },
          {
            "label": "Paperback",
            "id": 100,
            "data": "Paperback",
            "selected": false
          }
        ],`

From what I can gather, the variant pricing is only available via `cart.items`, but I need to display the prices before the user places an item in the cart.

Is there a way to get product variant pricing/info without using the `cart.items` object? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this via a stencil object.

On the product detail page I check if a product `has_options`, then make ajax calls to the variant URLs to get their prices to create a price range before the user selects their variants. This is pretty necessary when the vendor has huge price differences in variants.

ex.) "From $49.99 - $499.99" instead of "$49.99" default functionality.

I don't have a resolution for category pages as it doesn't make sense to make AJAX requests for each variant of each item on the category page on load. Once Stencil adds support for custom fields on the category page, you could add the child's prices to a parent SKUs custom field and perform some logic for whatever your trying to accomplish.

I don't know when custom fields will be available on the category page but [I know they are working on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467580/bigcommerce-stencil-retrieve-product-custom-fields-in-product-card).

Comment: Hi Tim. I read your linked question and I also will need to access custom fields on the category page (e.g., putting the Authors name next to the book title). Anyway, I was thinking of a similar solution to the ajax method you mention, but calling an external product feed for the info I need. But I would much rather that info be available within stencil as its already exposed via the legacy API.

Comment: The stencil API and the legacy/oauth API are independent implementations.