# Adding Custom Product Detail Fields in BigCommerce Stencil?

Tags: bigcommerce

We want to add custom fields that can be modified on the back end, yet also populate on the front end using custom fields. We have tried following, yet the fields didn't populate on the front end. See below for examples of the code and corresponding output:

[Example Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na1zX.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecmiT.png)

How can we get these fields to properly populate on the front end?

Answer (score 4):

I would start by reading the [BigCommerce Stencil Documentation](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/product-resources). The way you are calling the custom field values is not how they suggest calling these values.

The custom_fields are [only accessible on the product detail page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467580/bigcommerce-stencil-retrieve-product-custom-fields-in-product-card) at this time in Stencil.

To display them on the product detail page, you can loop through each custom_field value with the following code.

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
   <dt class="productView-info-name">{{name}}:</dt>
   <dd class="productView-info-value">{{{value}}}</dd>
{{/each}}
```

You can check to see what values are available on each page by either reading the Stencil docs linked above, or debugging your page by removing the closing '/' and adding '?debug=bar' to the end of your localhost URL. Refresh your page and you will see all available store data in JSON format below the rendered page.

Comment: what if you only want to call one of the fields. for example `{{product.custom_fields.id:4}}`

Comment: if you only want to call one of the fields, I recommend doing a check for the name of the field,

{{#each product.custom_fields}}
    {{#if name '===' 'desiredName'}}
          {{value}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}

This will loop through all of the custom_fields, and check if the name of the custom field matches the name of the custom field in the backend and will display the value if it matches.

You should also be able to do {{product.custom_fields.4.name}}
 and {{product.custom_fields.4.value}} if you want to display the 4th custom field name and value, respectively

Answer (score 0):

For more control over which custom field you output where you can create a reusable loop.

i.e. Create templates/components/products/custom-fields.html

```html
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
  {{#if name '===' ../custom_field}}  
    {{{value}}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Then from your product_view.html you can specify the field value to output with a single line:

```html
{{> components/products/custom-field custom_fields='custom field name'}}
```